# Error 404 Munin page not Found

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, munin

I installed Munin and munin-node on Server and httpd was already installed. But after installed when i run the munin-node the Browser gives me this error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /munin was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at 192.168.5.1 Port 80
```

I checked the /etc/munin.conf file and the path to Html directory is correct.

```
# Example configuration file for Munin, generated by 'make build'

# The next three variables specifies where the location of the RRD
# databases, the HTML output, and the logs, severally.  They all
# must be writable by the user running munin-cron.
dbdir   /var/lib/munin
htmldir /var/www/munin
logdir  /var/log/munin
rundir  /var/run/munin
```

And the Permission for /var/www/munin/ are set for munin:munin

## /etc/httpd/conf.d/munin.conf

```
# For SSL-servers
ScriptAlias /munin/cgi/ /var/www/munin/cgi/
#<Directory /var/www/munin/cgi/>
#   Options ExecCGI
#   SSLRequireSSL
#   order deny,allow
#   deny from all
#   AuthType Basic
#   AuthUserFile /site/cfg/passwd
#   AuthGroupFile /site/cfg/group
#   AuthName "munin"
#   require group munin
#   Satisfy Any
#</Directory>
#
Alias /munin/ /var/www/munin/
#<Directory /var/www/munin/>
#   Options None
#   SSLRequireSSL
#   order deny,allow
#   deny from all
#   AuthType Basic
#   AuthUserFile /site/cfg/passwd
#   AuthGroupFile /site/cfg/group
#   AuthName "munin"
#   require group munin
#   Satisfy Any
#</Directory>
```

## Apache Logs

```
[Sun Sep 01 04:03:12 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Sep 01 04:03:12 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Sep 01 04:03:12 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 01 11:34:47 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:15 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:15 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:15 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:16 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:18 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:18 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:18 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:18 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:18 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:41 2013] [error] [client 10.20.20.147] File does not exist: /var/www/html/munin
[Sun Sep 01 14:50:41 2013] [error] [client 10.20.20.147] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
```

## After un-commenting some files in /etc/httpd/conf.d/munin.conf

```
# For SSL-servers
ScriptAlias /munin/cgi/ /var/www/munin/cgi/
<Directory /var/www/munin/cgi/>
   Options ExecCGI
   #SSLRequireSSL
   order deny,allow
#   deny from all
   #deny from none
   allow from all
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /site/cfg/passwd
   AuthGroupFile /site/cfg/group
   AuthName "munin"
   require group munin
   Satisfy Any
</Directory>
#
Alias /munin/ /var/www/munin/
<Directory /var/www/munin/>
   Options None
   #SSLRequireSSL
   order deny,allow
#   deny from all
   #deny from none
   allow from all
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /site/cfg/passwd
   AuthGroupFile /site/cfg/group
   AuthName "munin"
   require group munin
   Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

Comment: Did you restart/reload apache? I am guessing it added a site or configuration file to point /munin to something other than /var/www/munin which probably doesn't exist. (or /var/www/html/munin)

Comment: Yes, I restarted the Apache many many times just waiting for miracle to happen. But I run out of blessings power right now. I added the /etc/httpd/conf.d/munin.conf data in question

Comment: If you could add the relevant errors in /var/log/httpd/error_log, it'd probably help.

Comment: added the httpd logs

Answer (score 1):

The HTML and PNG files are actually created, but the permission set on the file is 640 instead of 644, which `apache` is not able to read. So there is workaround for this. you should be running the munin as

```
su - munin --shell=/bin/bash munin-cron
```

This will update the graphs with 644 permission, and `apache` will be able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following lines in  `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
Alias /munin /var/www/munin
<Directory /var/www/munin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

save file, remove your whole munin configuration file and restart apache and munin-node.

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
 chkconfig --levels 235 munin-node on
 /etc/init.d/munin-node restart
```

Comment: Sorry I was out of city so i couldn't work on it. Now im back. I followed your instructions but it is still not working. I copied the recent change from /etc/httpd/con.f/munin.conf file and pasted in this thread. Please check

Comment: Please remove # from #deny from none line.

Comment: No man same error "The requested URL /munin was not found on this server.". This time I copied the folder from /var/www/munin/OP to /var/www/html/. Then restarted the httpd and munin-node but again got the same error